# JavaScript function that runs in a closed window

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to make a chronometer extension in Firefox. I have a function to count minutes and seconds, and it run backwards. The problem is: I call the function with a window.setInterval() method. So when the Firefox extension window is closed, the function stops. When the extension window is opened, it starts again. 
I want to call the function so it will run even if the extension window is closed. This way I can use several tabs in Firefox and the chronometer will run along them. 
Is there a way I can do this?

Here is my code, in JS:

```
let m = 25;
let s = 0;

let dm = 0;
let ds = 0;

function tomato() {

    if (s === 0) {
        m--;
        s = 59;
    }

    s--;

    if (s < 10) {
        ds = "0" + s.toString();
    } else {
        ds = s;
    }
    if (m < 10) {
        dm = "0" + m.toString();
    } else {
        dm = m;
    }
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = dm + ":" + ds;
}

window.setInterval(tomato, 1000);
```

Comment: Keeping track of time by incrementing/decrementing a variable at a given interval is not always precise, and especially not when it runs for a long time _(it tends to drift slowly)_, or when the browser decides to lower the rate of the calls _(For example, Chrome throttles intervals when a tab is not in focus)_. Checking the difference between now and a start timestamp is always precise, and does not require your interval to keep working continuously